# How to solve this differential equation with a square root?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I've to solve this differential equation but I don't know how to do it. Someone can help me?

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} \Bigg( -1 - \frac{2a}{\sqrt{a^2 - 3x L f^2 e^{3y}}} \Bigg)$

where a, L and f are costant.

I've tried to solve it in Mathematica with DSolve in this way:

```
DSolve[1/x (-1 - (2 a/Sqrt[a^2 - 3 x L f^2 Exp[3 y[x]]])) == y'[x], 
 y[x], x]
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Is this question about the _Mathematica_ software? If not, this question is better suited for math.stackexchange. If you are asking about the _Mathematica_ software, could you include what you have tried?

Comment: yes it's about Mathematica software and I've tried with DSolve

Comment: Please include what you have already tried with DSolve in your question

Comment: Your DSolve works in 12.2 without providing values to the constants, and gives multiple solutions of the form `y[x]->Log[Root[...]]`

Comment: `a = 1; f = 1; L = 1; DSolve[
 1/x (-1 - (2 a/Sqrt[a^2 - 3 x L f^2 Exp[3 y[x]]])) == y'[x], y[x], x]` produces a useless output. Try `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: Maple 2021 performs $$ \ln \! \left(x \right)-\frac{\ln \! \left(\sqrt{a^{2}-3 x L \,f^{2} {\mathrm e}^{3 y \left(x \right)}}+a \right)}{4}+\frac{\ln \! \left(\sqrt{a^{2}-3 x L \,f^{2} {\mathrm e}^{3 y \left(x \right)}}-a \right)}{8}+\frac{9 \ln \! \left(\sqrt{a^{2}-3 x L \,f^{2} {\mathrm e}^{3 y \left(x \right)}}+3 a \right)}{8}-\textit{\_C1}
 = 0
.$$

Comment: MMA version 12.1 works when you specify: `Assumptions -> {L, f, a} \[Element] Reals`

Comment: thanks very much to everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica seems to have problems with `Sqrt`. "Squaring" gives

```
ode = ( -(2 a/Sqrt[a^2 - 3 x L f^2 Exp[3 y[x]]]))^2 == (x y'[x] + 1)^2     
(*(4 a^2)/(a^2 - 3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x) == (1 + x Derivative[1][y][x])^2*)
```

`DSolve`is now able to solve the ode

```
DSolve[ode, y[x], x][[1]]
(*Solve[(3 (6 Sqrt[a^2 x^2 (a^2 - 3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x)]
      ArcTan[Sqrt[-a^2 + 3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x]/(3 a)] - 
    2 Sqrt[a^2 x^2 (a^2 - 3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x)]
      ArcTan[Sqrt[-a^2 + 3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x]/a] + 
    a x Sqrt[-a^2 + 
      3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x] (5 Log[x] + 
       3 Log[8 a^2 + 3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x])))/(16 a x Sqrt[-a^2 + 
   3 E^(3 y[x]) f^2 L x]) - (3 y[x])/16 == C[1], y[x]]*)
```

As the Maple result, Mathematica evaluates an implicit equation in `y[x]`!

Comment: You obtain a non-equivalent ODE by squaring.

Comment: This ode includes all solution branches of the original ode!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by flinty [in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243746/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation-with-a-square-root/243817#comment613479_243746), *v12.2* can solve the problem directly, with a `Solve::ifun` warning generated. If you need the implicit solution as given by *Maple*, you can:

```
Trace[
  DSolve[1/x (-1 - (2 a/Sqrt[a^2 - 3 x L f^2 Exp[3 y[x]]])) == y'[x], y[x], x], 
  Solve[_, y[x]], TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten
(* 
  {HoldForm[
    Solve[(3/8)*(3*Log[a - Sqrt[a^2 - 3*E^(3*y[x])*f^2*L*x]] + 
        2*Log[a + Sqrt[a^2 - 3*E^(3*y[x])*f^2*L*x]] + 
                3*Log[3*a + Sqrt[a^2 - 3*E^(3*y[x])*f^2*L*x]]) - 3*y[x] == C[1], y[x]]]}
 *)
```